# Omake getenv -- environment variables are not found

Tags: getenv, omake

Some environment variables that exist in my bash environment (set in .bashrc) are not being read by getenv (it's saying they're undefined). Is it looking in some other environment? or....?

```
monster@Tangerine ~/Casey/piano-core $ omake
*** omake: reading OMakefiles
--- Checking for ocamlfind... (found /home/monster/ocamlbrew/ocaml-4.02.3/.opam/4.02.2/bin/ocamlfind)
--- Checking for ocamlc.opt... (found /home/monster/ocamlbrew/ocaml-4.02.3/.opam/4.02.2/bin/ocamlc.opt)
--- Checking for ocamlopt.opt... (found /home/monster/ocamlbrew/ocaml-4.02.3/.opam/4.02.2/bin/ocamlopt.opt)
--- Checking whether ocamlc understands the "z" warnings... (yes)
*** omake error:
   File _build/score-player/stubs/OMakefile: line 14, characters 8-30
   undefined environment variable: SCORE_PLAYER
monster@Tangerine ~/Casey/piano-core $ $SCORE_PLAYER
bash: /home/monster/Casey/score-player: Is a directory
monster@Tangerine ~/Casey/piano-core $ rlwrap osh
% getenv(SCORE_PLAYER)
*** omake error:
   File -: line 1, characters 0-20
   undefined environment variable: SCORE_PLAYER
%
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I solved this by putting the variables in /etc/environment rather than ~/.bashrc. I guess I don't have a very good understanding of which environments are which....